# Cake PHP - Conditional validation checks

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I'm fairly new to Cake PHP. I searched this site and many others, as well as the Cake cookbook and the API for an answer to my question but couldn't find any.

The system I am working on uses soft deletes to remove users. I am looking for a way to use conditional validation checks when a user tries to create a new account to do the following:

1. Check for soft deleted records with the same email as the email input field.
2. If a soft deleted record is found, the validation should pass, and the soft deleted record should have deleted set to false, and have any fields entered by the user overwrite the existing fields in the soft deleted record.
3. If the email didn't exist in the soft deleted user records, then another check should be performed to see if the email exists in the user records at all.
4. If the email doesn't exist, then the validation should pass and a new user account should be created.
5. If the email does exist, then the validation should fail and the message "This email already exists in our records, please pick another or contact your administrator."

Something like this:

```
public function checkForDeleted($email) {
    // Check if email exists as a soft-deleted record
    $deleted_user = $this->findByEmailAndDeleted($email, true)
    if (empty($deleted)) {
        // If email doesn't exist as a soft-deleted record check for uniqueness
        $unique_email = $this->findByEmail($email);
        if (empty($unique_email)) {
            // If email is unique, return valid and create new user
        }
        else {
            // If email is not unique, return invalid and do nothing else
        }
    }
    else {
        // If email exists as soft deleted record, return valid and re-activate soft-deleted user
    }
}
```

I think I am on the right track, I just have no idea where to go from here, and can't find any answers despite hours of searching online. Am I on the right track? Where do I need to go from here?

Thankyou in advance for any assistance

Comment: You need to state which version of CakePHP you are using.

Comment: u are after conditional validation: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#conditional-validation